# How can I compare a date and a datetime in Python?

Tags: python

Here's a little snippet that I'm trying execute:

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> item_date = datetime.strptime('7/16/10', "%m/%d/%y")
>>> from_date = date.today()-timedelta(days=3)
>>> print type(item_date)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> print type(from_date)
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> if item_date > from_date:
...     print 'item is newer'
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

I can't seem to compare the date and the datetime values. What would be the best way to compare these? Should I convert the datetime to date or vice-versa? How do i convert between them.

(A small question but it seems to be a little confusing.)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239315/cant-compare-datetime-datetime-to-datetime-date

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use [the `.date()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to convert a datetime to a date:

```
if item_date.date() > from_date:
```

Alternatively, you could use [`datetime.today()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) instead of `date.today()`. You could use

```
from_date = from_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

to eliminate the time part afterwards.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if it's given that item_date will always be a datetime and from_date will always be a date.   I landed here because I wanted to sort a list containing both date and datetime.  In my case, the approach above is probably the worst.

Comment: why is the conversion necessary? I thought that internally python uses a unixtimestamp for `date` and `datetime`. Or is `date` more resource optimized in that it only looks for date and not time?

Answer (score 7):

I am trying to compare date which are in string format like **'20110930'**

```
benchMark = datetime.datetime.strptime('20110701', "%Y%m%d") 

actualDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('20110930', "%Y%m%d")

if actualDate.date() < benchMark.date():
    print True
```

Comment: If you have string format YYYYMMDD string comparison is equivalent to converting to date and comparing dates and is more efficient.

Comment: string comparison is more efficient?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another take which preserves information in case both the inputs are datetimes and not dates, "stolen" from a comment at [can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239315/cant-compare-datetime-datetime-to-datetime-date) ... convert the date to a datetime using this construct:

```
datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)
```

Suggestion:

```
from datetime import datetime

def ensure_datetime(d):
    """
    Takes a date or a datetime as input, outputs a datetime
    """
    if isinstance(d, datetime):
        return d
    return datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)

def datetime_cmp(d1, d2):
    """
    Compares two timestamps.  Tolerates dates.
    """
    return cmp(ensure_datetime(d1), ensure_datetime(d2))
```

Answer (score 3):

I got you bro

you can use  timetuple function to compare between date obj and datetime obj

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime               
>>> date_obj=datetime.utcnow().date() 
>>> type(date_obj)
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> datetime_obj=datetime.utcnow()    
>>> type(datetime_obj)            
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> datetime_obj.timetuple()          
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=2, tm_min=12, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=284, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> date_obj.timetuple()     
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=284, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> type(datetime_obj.timetuple())
<type 'time.struct_time'>
>>> type(date_obj.timetuple()) 
<type 'time.struct_time'>
>>> date_obj.timetuple()<datetime_obj.timetuple()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I get two objects in and I don't know if it's date or timedate objects.  Converting to date won't be good as I'd be dropping information - two timedate objects with the same date should be sorted correctly.  I'm OK with the dates being sorted before the datetime with same date.

I think I will use strftime before comparing:

```
>>> foo=datetime.date(2015,1,10)
>>> bar=datetime.datetime(2015,2,11,15,00)
>>> foo.strftime('%F%H%M%S') > bar.strftime('%F%H%M%S')
False
>>> foo.strftime('%F%H%M%S') < bar.strftime('%F%H%M%S')
True
```

Not elegant, but should work out.  I think it would be better if Python wouldn't raise the error, I see no reasons why a datetime shouldn't be comparable with a date.  This behaviour is consistent in python2 and python3.

Answer (score 1):

Create and similar object for comparison works too
ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

now = datetime.now()
today = date.today()

# compare now with today
two_month_earlier = date(now.year, now.month - 2, now.day)
if two_month_earlier > today:
    print(True)

two_month_earlier = datetime(now.year, now.month - 2, now.day)
if two_month_earlier > now:
   print("this will work with datetime too")
```