# can't compare datetime.datetime to builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am new in Django.

I created Sponsor model that model has `start_date` (start date become sponsor) and `end_date` (end date of sponsor).

```
start_date = models.DateField(
        _("Start date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)

end_date = models.DateField(
        _("End date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)
```

I want to put all logic inside the model, if that not possible then I want to put the logic in a view. I make method `current_sponsor` which can return True or False (if today is on a range of start_date and end_date means `True` else `False`).

This is my `current_sponsor` method

```
def current_sponsor(self):
        today = datetime.date.today
        if today >= self.start_date:
            return True
        elif today <= self.end_date:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem is I got error `can't compare datetime.datetime to builtin_function_or_method`.

I've tried to see the data using django shell it seem works but the reality does not work.

Comment: ...you're missing parentheses.

Comment: @rischan No offense, but it would _really_ benefit you to start actually reading the exception messages... They couldn't be any clearer, but if they're not a simple search will make it so; these errors you got have been asked a million times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime.date.today` is not calling the function you think it is:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today
<built-in method today of type object at 0x7fb681a90f80>  # NOT CALLING FUNCTION

>>> datetime.date.today()  # You need () at the end
datetime.date(2015, 11, 4)
```

If you add the parentheses, you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks @jonrshape Now I realized that I miss parentheses, but when I put parentheses I am still get error `can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`.

Comment: As the exception says, one of the dates you're comparing is a `datetime.datetime` object and one is a `datetime.date` object. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239315/cant-compare-datetime-datetime-to-datetime-date).

Comment: I changed everything to `today = datetime.datetime.today()` and now I get different error `can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
`

Comment: @rischan this is a Django "feature." I'm going to assume you're using Django 1.4... check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652819/django-1-4-cant-compare-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes) which discusses your exact issue.

Comment: Thanks Tgsmith61591 it because of utc. I've replace it with `replace(tzinfo=utc):` and it works.