# Python check that the date is 30 days in the future

Tags: python

I want to write a test, that takes a time from a saved object `recipient.expiry_date` and checks that the date is 30 days in the future.

This is what I have tried:

```
days_to_match = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30)

self.assertEqual(recipient.expiry_date, days_to_match)
```

Because it also contains the time this won't match.

How can this be done?

Please note that  `recipient.expiry_date` is set in my model using `timezone.now()`so comparison on dates from python seemed to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look at the date portions:

```
self.assertEqual(recipient.expiry_date.year, days_to_match.year)
self.assertEqual(recipient.expiry_date.month, days_to_match.month)
self.assertEqual(recipient.expiry_date.day, days_to_match.day)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279015/912757), you can use the `date()` to compare only the date and not the time. Or you can put the time data = 0.

```
self.assertEqual(recipient.expiry_date.date(), days_to_match.date())
```