# How to convert a date value to date type for comparison?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm reading a date value from the user and need to do a date comparison for that in django. I could not find any answer how to do that. What I exactly need is get the string converted to date so that it can be compared for equality/less than/greater than value.

I obtain the form value as follows.

```
start_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['start_date']
```

I need to compare start_date value with `date.today()` for equality/less than/greater than.

Can anyone let me know **exact way to do this**. I don't read any time portion from the input since I set the form input as a `date` field (not `datetime`).

**Update to full code:**

In the form declaration:

```
class Form_Task(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(label='Check-In Date', initial='2017-05-05',
                                   widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control,'size': 10}))
```

In the POST request:

```
form_new_task = Form_Task(request.POST)
    if form_new_task.is_valid():
        start_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['start_date']

        if start_date < date.today()
            err_str = 'Start date cannot be a past date.' # here I don't get this assigned. It's evaluate to False.
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If `start_date` is a `DateField`, then `cleaned_data['start_date']` should already be a date instance.

Comment: Use the `.date()` Method this will help you see [Compare a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278999/how-can-i-compare-a-date-and-a-datetime-in-python)

Comment: I get the following error when calling the date() method

`if start_date.date() < date.today(): # error line`

`'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: **Because it is already a date**. You literally don't need to convert anything.

Comment: Also, this comparison should be taking place as part of the form's validation. You should do it in a `clean_start_date` method on the form class.

Comment: @Alasdair I've put all code. But my comparison simple fails. Are you that I get the start_date as a date object when read? Why then the comparison fails?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is this means I never can compare two dates other than clean_xxx method?

Comment: No. Those are two completely separate points (which is why they are in separate comments). You can compare dates wherever you like; but this particular comparison belongs inside the form, because is_valid should not be true if the start_date is before today.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not clear why still I can't compare it here. (I'm bit new to python/django). From code experiment (calling `.date()` for both values) I learn that both objects are type date. But I can not simply compare them.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not simply compare them"?

Comment: It never get evaluate to True if I set a past date to the start_date. Please refer the above original code in the Updated section. Not even an error is shown in the execution.

Comment: The comparison `if start_date < date.today():` looks ok. Only you can debug this, because you have the code in front of you and can add logging or print statements. Check that the form is really valid. Check the value of `start_date` and `date.today`.

Comment: @Alasdair I got it worked. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do this and thought this would be helpful to others. I have declared the start_date field as DateField and when I read the value it get as a date type object (datetime actually I think). So I have to get a delta (difference) within these two for days only.

**Form:**

```
class Form_Task(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField() # declaration
```

**In the post request handler method:**

```
    form_new_task = Form_Task(request.POST)

    if form_new_task.is_valid():
      start_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['start_date']
      delta = start_date - date.today()

      if delta.days < 0:
        err_str = 'Start date cannot be a past date.'
      elif delta.days == 0:
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: If you have a `DateField` then `cleaned_data['start_date']` will be a `date`, not a `datetime`. You can create a delta if you want, but you don't have to do this. Simply `if start_date < date.today():` should work. Finally, as Daniel suggested, it would be better to add a `clean_start_date` method to your form and do the check there (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for more info).

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair. I tried that way and it won't work. But getting the delta worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You could compare the dates like this,

```
from datetime import datetime

if start_date < datetime.today().date():
    err_str = 'Start date cannot be a past date.'
```

Comment: I can not pass the `start_date` to the `strptime`. It says `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date` which means it is already a date object. They why I can't compare it with `date.today()`. I need the correct function or a code to compare these. Also I can't call `datetime.datetime.today().date()`. It gives the same error.

Comment: If its a date object then why can't you compare it with date.toda()?? It should work..

Comment: Please refer the answer I posted. I think that way much clear as I can compare various situations depending on the value returned.